# Flask - TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'user_id'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I used Python to insert data, I had the following problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/python/dbFlask/web/models.py", line 42, in <module>
    env = Env()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'user_id'
```

My **init**.py like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 
"mysql+pymysql://root:123@127.0.0.1:3306/env"
```

The key code of my operateDB.py like this:

```
class Env(db.Model):

    def __init__(self, name, user_id):
        self.name = name
        self.user_id = user_id

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
env = Env()
env.name = 'test01'
env.user_id = '1'
db.session.add(env)
db.session.commit()
```

The problem happened after I run the operateDB.py. I can't find the solution of the problem.

Comment: You are trying to create a new `Env()` without passing it a name and user_id as required in the line `def __init__(self, name, user_id):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `__init__` method from your models, it's not necessary.

> Note how we never defined a **init** method on the User class? That’s because SQLAlchemy adds an implicit constructor to all model classes which accepts keyword arguments for all its columns and relationships. If you decide to override the constructor for any reason, make sure to keep accepting **kwargs and call the super constructor with those **kwargs to preserve this behavior:

With the `__init__` method defined you get a `TypeError`

```
class User(db.Model):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    env = db.relationship('Env', backref='env')


class Env(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, name, user_id):
        self.name = name
        self.user_id = user_id

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


>>> from app import *
>>> u1 = User()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
>>> e1 = Env()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'user_id'
>>>
```

The best way to define your models is shown in the [documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/)

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    env = db.relationship('Env', backref='env')


class Env(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

>>> from app import db, User, Env
>>> u1 = User()
>>> u1.name = 'user'
>>> db.session.add(u1)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> env1 = Env()
>>> env1.name='env'
>>> env1.user_id=u1.id)
>>> db.session.add(env1)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> env1
<Env 1>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object in Python it calls `__init__()` method, in your case you have 2 arguments in `__init__(self, name, user_id)` method, so you should provide those 2 values while creating an object of `Env` like `env = Env('test01', '1')`

So instead of

```
env = Env()
env.name = 'test01'
env.user_id = '1'
```

Use

```
env = Env('test01', '1')
```